# Azure App Registration using Managed Identities instead of Client Secrets

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, microsoft-identity-web, azure-app-registration

Im using the Microsoft Identity Web package latest (2.6.2) in .NET Core 7.0 to secure my front end app, which in turn calls a down stream api (API Gateway)

In order to call the downstream API, we have to configure a client secret which is stored in the client's App Registration in Azure.

[image]

Currently the "ClientSecret" could be stored in either the apps local settings (during dev) or the secrets.json file. I understand others have chosen to store the secret in Azure Key Vault, or possibly using an X509 cert instead which can achieve longer expiry time.

I'm actually in the process of migrating away using from connections strings/keys to using Azure Managed Identities to connect with the different services, for the simple reason of eliminating the challenge in key rotation which in a production environment just adds more pain.

**Question** - Even if not currently available, is Azure planning to extend the use of Azure Managed Identities as an option to eliminate the use of client secrets and the laborious secret key rotation process in App Registrations? Using Azure vault is all well and good but it doesnt solve the challenge for keys that evetually expire and need to be rotated, the onyly added value I see is the emans to remove the secret from the apps'code...

I'm looking a solution like the example below (which may not currently exisit)

```
// Using DefaultAzureCredential() instead of a client secret
// ---------------------------------------------------------
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new DefaultAzureCredential()) 
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphBeta"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

If this is never going to happen, then one other options might be fetching the clinet secret from Azure Key Vault, the secret itself would ideally need to have an expiry longer than the current maximum 2 years.

I'm not sure if its possible to extend the expiry of the secret, Azure used to allow this as I'm still using one during development that was set to expire 12/31/2299.

Nowadays we get the "computer says no" greeting
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, it's better to use **client certificates** that will be more secure and stay long compared to client secrets.

*If still **client secret** is your use case, you can check below results that I reproduced in my environment:*

I got the **same error** as below when I tried to create client secret with expiry date as `12/31/2299` like this:

[image]

> Note that, creating client secrets with custom expiry time of **more than 2 years** from Azure
> Portal(UI) is removed and no longer supported but you can still create them via PowerShell, Graph API etc...

I ran below **Graph API** query to create client secret with expiry date as `12/31/2299` in [***Graph Explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<appObjectID>/addPassword

{
    "passwordCredential": {
        "displayName": "secret",
        "endDateTime": "2299-12-31"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, secret is created successfully with long **expiry date** as below:

[image]

To create **client secret** with long expiry from PowerShell, you can make use of below commands:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(300)
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId 05b72b0a-0345-42b4-8ea2-a909e3eacb0c -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -CustomKeyIdentifier pssecret
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, another **client secret** created with long expiry time as below:

[image]

**References:**

[Future plans of Microsoft with the maximum expiration of a client secret - Microsoft Q&A by **James Tran**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/422538/future-plans-of-microsoft-with-the-maximum-expirat)

Comment: Sounds like their is no plan to make Managed Identities integrate in a way to avoid the client secret bit here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be considered good practice but I use ManagedIdentity to generate the client secret using Microsoft Graph API in Startup.cs

```
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(microsoftIdentityOptions => {
    ...
    microsoftIdentityOptions.ClientSecret = GenerateClientSecretAsync().Result;
    ...
})

private static async Task<string> GenerateClientSecretAsync() {
    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new ManagedIdentityCredential(), scopes: new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
    AddPasswordPostRequestBody requestBody = new AddPasswordPostRequestBody {
        PasswordCredential = new PasswordCredential {
            DisplayName = "Password for MyApp",
        },
    };
    PasswordCredential passwordCredential = await graphServiceClient.Applications['MyApp object id...'].AddPassword.PostAsync(requestBody); //Requires "Application.ReadWrite.All" permission for the ManagedIdentity
    return passwordCredential.SecretText;
}
```

1. You need to add "Application.ReadWrite.All" permission to the app ManagedIdentity using Powershell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-assign-app-role-managed-identity-powershell)
2. You need to add Microsoft Graph API Nuget package.
3. Calling Result() on Async function is probably bad. You can change it to if you want.

With this, I don't have to keep the client secret somewhere. I don't even have to know the client secret. If I want to extend the expiration date, I just need to restart the app which probably can be done on a scheduled basis.

Over time, there will be unused or expired client secret left. I create a cleanup function calling Microsoft Graph API to delete those.