# Is it possible to use a user-assigned managed identity with an App Registration in Azure?

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-app-registration

Let's say I have two API services **A** and **B** and I want to provide role-based access control for calls to either of them. Currently I create an App Registration for both **A** and **B** and then define roles on those app registrations as needed.

So my requirements are:

- I need to define roles for **A** and **B** that users/groups/services can be assigned to.
- I need to securely authenticate API services when talking to other API services.

Since I've created App Registrations for **A** and **B** I also have [automatically generated Enterprise Applications/Service Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals?tabs=browser) which seem like the preferred identity I should use to authenticate **A** when talking to **B**. However this requires me to store a client secret or [certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75847329/azure-app-registration-using-managed-identities-instead-of-client-secrets) somewhere (such as a Key Vault) that **A** can use during authentication which in turn means more management and having to store them and rotate them.

I need the "role definition" mechanism provided by App Registrations, but if I could use [Managed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Cpowershell#connect-to-azure-services-in-app-code) in place of the Enterprise Application/Service Principal I could go fully password-less and reduce maintenance overhead.

I know I can't select a managed identity when creating an App Registration in the UI, but is this possible through the CLI/Graph or something else? And is this the "correct" way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I realise that I can use the App Registration+Service Principal for role definitions and a managed identity for authentication, but then I get an unused Service Principal directly connected to the App Registration. That does not seem ideal.